# Copy a .prj-file from another shapefile to a new one when the projection is known?

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, prj

I have a bunch of shapefiles of which I know the projection (EPSG:28992). However, they did not come with a prj-file (.prj).

Rather than defining the projection and re-saving the files, I wonder whether it would be okay to copy (and rename) the prj-file from another shapefile which is in the same projection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That has always worked fine for me.

Also if you know the projection but don't have an example to copy you can fetch one from http://epsg.io

Answer (score 0):

Yes copying and renaming a .prj file is an adequate way of assigning projection to a shapefile.

But it could be safer/easier to do it differently as a typo during renaming may go unnoticed and cause the .prj to not be read.

(If you use ArcGIS setting a projection simply add the .prj and do not require to resave the file)